# General solution of $a\sin(b+x)=x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

What is the general solution of the equation $a\sin(b+x)=x$ for $x$? I am interested in the case, when $0<a<1$. I tried to solve it the following way: calculate the left side when $x=0$. Then replaced $x$ with the calculated left side. I have iterated these 2 steps, and it really converged to a solution. Is there a better way to find the general solution? At the end, I need the function $f(b)=x$, where $a$ is a constants. For example when $a=0.9$ I got the following plot for $f(b)$ where $0<b<2\pi$. I am sure there is[image] a category for these kind of equation in math but I do not know the terms for these.

Comment: No reason to have both $a$ and $c.$

Comment: well, that's true. I edit the question accordingly.

Comment: It converged to "a" solution. Usually there will be more than one, so $x=f(b)$ doesn't make sense without additional restrictions.

Comment: Unless $|a|\le1$ there will be multiple solutions. So you might want to consider the problem in stages. First, the case when $a=1$, then the case when $0<a<1$.

Comment: You are right, I edit the question. I am interested in the first case.

Comment: @ShirohimeHajikuji: Since $x$ is both inside and outside a trig function, your equation is ["transcendental"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) and resists analytical, closed-form solution using elementary functions. Typically, numerical methods are required; in some cases, a special function (such as [Lambert's $W$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) can help.